# How can I install Ubuntu on a HP Pavillion DM1 with broken USB ports?

Tags: boot, networking, system-installation, hp

I was recently given an old computer (HP Pavilon Dm1 - I think it's about 6 years old). All 3 USB ports on the computer are broken. So I have to install Ubuntu through Internet network adapter boot, but I'm a little lost how to do that. I was planning to install Ubuntu 19.04 to this old computer on SSD drive.

How can I install Ubuntu on a device with broken USB ports?

Answer (score 0):

1.Download Unetbootin

2.Run Unetbootin.

3.Now, from the drop-down menu under Type: select Hard Disk.

4.Next select the Diskimage. Browse to the directory where you downloaded the iso      file of Ubuntu.

5. Next when you reboot, you will get a menu like this:
6. Unetbootin
7. Select Unetbootin and you will get the "Try" or "Install" option there.
8. Finally, you can install your version of Ubuntu alongside Windows.